# Preventing duplication when importing the same CSS file in different files

Tags: angular, sass, tailwind-css

I have an Angular project that uses Sass for the CSS processing, and I'm looking at Tailwind. I want to import Tailwind into various component Sass files so I can extend off them, but I saw when I import the same file twice, it's in the Angular generated files twice.

Is there some way or some method of organizing wherein I could avoid the duplication? Or am I thinking about the problem wrong?

Comment: The SASS file you're importing can not output any CSS styles. It should only contain mixins, variables and things like that.

Comment: It's the Tailwind output file, so that's not a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Importing sass file into different components results in each component having a copies of whatever is declared or defined in that sass file.  Now that's OK for variables and mixins since the compiler can optimize away same matching variable names and mixins but not so for regular classes because your defined classes will end-up being scoped to the component using custom name-mangling per component.  Thus each component will generated css will house the same class with a slightly named/appended attribute.

You should import your tailwindcss probably into your global style.scss perhaps to avoid duplication.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8431